# Remove graph tick marks on edges of ZedGraph

Tags: c#, winforms, zedgraph

Is it possible to remove the top and right major and minor tick marks on the graph edge in ZedGraph, while leaving the bottom and left tick marks in place?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a `bool` property `IsOpposite` in the `MinorTic` and `MajorTic` components of the axes. If you set the property to `false` the tic marks will not show on the right and top borders.

Here is an example:

```
var pane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;

pane.YAxisList[0].MajorTic.IsOpposite = false;
pane.YAxisList[0].MinorTic.IsOpposite = false;
pane.XAxis.MajorTic.IsOpposite = false;
pane.XAxis.MinorTic.IsOpposite = false;

pane.AddCurve(null, new[] { 0.1, 0.5, 0.9 }, new[] { 0.8, 0.3, 0.1 }, Color.Blue);
```

that will produce the following graph:

[image: No tick marks on upper and right borders]

Comment: That doesn't remove the ticks along the right and top edge borders, though.

Comment: Sorry for not reading the question thoroughly enough in the first round. Hopefully the updated answer gives you what you are asking for.